# Is it possible to pop to a specific view in the poppover when dismissing popover?

Tags: ios

I have a popover that has a main view that is used to pick from several sub-views and I'd like to reset the popover to the main view when the user taps outside of the popover and closes the window.

For example, the main popover view has Options, Categories, WordList, and Results. I'd like to make it so that the next time the user invokes the popover, they go to the main view rather than back to the view they were on when they last closed the popover.

If I'm only one level deep, I can use

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

But if I'm deep in a hierarchy, e.g. WordList:Category:Words I can't pop to root in WordList or Category since when the view disappears, I want to go to the next level down. If I use the code listed above, I can't get down a level. I pop to the root view.

What I'd like is to be able to tell the popover view to pop to its root when it's dismissed. Something like this:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    [[self popover] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initializing the popover, I test to see if it already exists. If so, I skip the initialization and go directly to the popover. That's why, when the popover is dismissed, it stays in whatever view the user left it in.

To make it start at the first view, I just need to set the popover to nil.

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popOverController {

    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popoverController = nil;
```

Now when the user invokes the popover, it creates a new set of views, starting with the main menu.

Comment: I assumed there was a reason you needed to preserve the state of the popover from one "appearance" to the next.  If not, this is probably the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is UIPopoverController's `contentViewController` property, which will be whatever view controller you initialized the popover with--most likely that navigation controller.  This...

[self.popover.contentViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

...should do the trick for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the UIViewController does not have the method 'popToRootViewController'.

Comment: Then I'm a little curious how you're initializing the popover. `[self.popover.contentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` might work instead.  If it doesn't, please post the code where you initialize the popover so I can understand how you're doing it.

Comment: Can't get the blog to let me post the code, but the relevant line is  `[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:buttonPressed permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];`

Comment: I need the initialization, as in `self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:XXXXX];` The XXXXX is what will be the popover controller's contentViewController property.